# postgresql - condition met in a time interval

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table and I want to create the `condition_met` column. The `condition_met` column is my expected output.

```
            timestamp  | client_id| type_id | prospect_id | condition_met
'2015-06-13 13:45:58'  | 240      | 34.     | 480         |TRUE
'2015-06-13 13:45:59'  | 480      | 56.     | 480         |FALSE
'2015-06-13 13:46:00'  | 480      | 76.     | 480         |FALSE
'2015-06-13 13:46:01'  | 480      | 76.     | 480         |FALSE
'2015-06-13 13:46:02'  | 240      | 35.     | 240         |FALSE
'2015-06-13 13:47:01'  | 480      | 34.     | 240         |FALSE
'2015-06-13 13:47:03'  | 240      | 56.     | 240         |FALSE
'2015-06-13 13:47:04'  | 240      | 76.     | 240         |FALSE
'2015-06-13 13:47:06'  | 240      | 76.     | 240         |FALSE
'2015-06-13 13:47:09'  | 480      | 98.     | 480         |FALSE
 ...
```

Condition_met is TRUE when `type_id = 34` and within 5 seconds after this `type_id`, the `client_id` of `type_id = 34` becomes also `prospect_id`.

To say it differently: for each type_id = 34 the client_id that performed action type_id = 34 needs to become prospect_id in 5 seconds

Comment: Please also write your expected output for this table

Comment: The expected output is the column `condition_met`

Comment: How can we join prospect_id and client_id ? What is the rule ?

Comment: prospect_id and client_id are performing actions of certain type_id. What matters here is when client_id performs action type 34. I want to check if the condition is met for this type of action.

Comment: How can we detect that `the client_id of type_id = 34 becomes also prospect_id` ?

Comment: we can detect it when client_id (of action type_id 34) == prospect_id within 5 seconds.

Comment: @MattnDo Why don't `type_id= 76` get the `true` result? because can match your logic.(`client_id== prospect_id within 5 seconds.`)

Comment: the second type_id doesn't TRUE because client_id == prospect_id outside the 5 seconds window. 13h47m01s vs 13h47m09s

Comment: @MattnDo but the `'2015-06-13 13:47:01' - '2015-06-13 13:45:58'` will be more than 5 second

Comment: it needs to be for each type_id 34 separately sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this query OK for you ? ([Resul here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5GMx6XeSsXb4dQqBnkU9T2/2))

```
with operations as (
select *,lead(client_id,1) over(order by client_id,timestamp_op),lead(prospect_id,1) over(order by client_id,timestamp_op),timestamp_op + interval '5s',
case 
    when type_id = 34 and lead(client_id,1) over(order by client_id,timestamp_op) = client_id 
    and lead(client_id,1) over(order by client_id,timestamp_op) = lead(prospect_id,1) over(order by client_id,timestamp_op) 
    and lead(timestamp_op,1) over(order by client_id,timestamp_op) <=timestamp_op + interval '5s' then true 
    else false 
end as condition_met
from operation
order by 2,1
)
select timestamp_op,client_id,type_id,prospect_id,condition_met from operations order by timestamp_op
```

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work because it returns TRUE for the second occurence of type_id = 34 when it shouldn't (see my example). It's because the condition has to be met for each type_id = 34

Comment: Yes the condition is met. type_id = 34 and next_client_id = next_prospect_id and interval is in 5 seconds. If the condition must be false you have to explain why.

Comment: the second type_id = 34 is FALSE because the next occurence of client_id == prospect_id is outside the 5 seconds window: 13h47m01s vs 13h47m09s

Comment: I'm sorry but your explanation are not clear at all. Tell us clearly what are the conditions that we have to respect. We only have a few part of what you want to do.

Comment: For each type_id = 34 the client_id that performed action type_id = 34 needs to become prospect_id in 5 seconds.

Comment: Ok I have modified the query to answer your needs.